# Run external program

Tags: java, runtime, exe

I can't run my ssh-keygen.exe. Output said build successful but the code should execute the .exe and display the application. This is my code

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class SSHConnectPing {

    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        try
        {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\ExecuteSSH\\ssh-keygen.exe");
        }
        catch(Exception exc)
        {
            System.out.println("error" + exc);/*handle exception*/
        }
    }
}
```

What should I do? Please help me.

Comment: There isn't much information to go on when it comes to fixing this, but in general I would recommend you take a look at Apache Commons Exec (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/), it makes executing other applications in Java a lot less painful

Comment: thanks jason, actually i just copy paste the code from the net to see how i can run my ssh-keygen.exe . while i read the document you gave me. can anybody show me the working code to execute .exe application in java. thanks again jason and all who helped

Comment: What is the error that is generated? i.e. what output do you see in the system.out.printline("error" + exc) etc? Also, did you try running this in debug mode so that you get better look at the exception generated?

Comment: Thanks Jason now  i can execute my .exde application

My code now is (import apache common exe and tutorial at http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/tutorial.html)

String line = "C:\\ExecuteSSH\\ssh-keygen.exe";
        CommandLine cmdLine = CommandLine.parse(line);
        DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
        
        //watchdog
        executor.setExitValue(1);
        ExecuteWatchdog watchdog = new ExecuteWatchdog(60000);
        executor.setWatchdog(watchdog);
        
        int exitValue = executor.execute(cmdLine);

Comment: thanks robnick, there are no error display while compiled but i found the solution. stack overflow wont let me answer my own question so i just post my answer at comment. sorry if the answer above is unreadable

Comment: how do i rate people comment into answer? sorry i am new here

Comment: I've removed "answer" from the question; I would encourage you to post the answer as a bona fide answer instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java newcomer like me who are looking on how to execute external application (.exe) you can try this sample:

```
// get apache.common.exec.jar at:
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/download_exec.cgi

import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.exec.CommandLine;
import org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor;
import org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteWatchdog;


public class RunRsync {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    try {

    //example :  String line = "C://file.exe";
    String line = "cmd /c start";   //you can put your .exe path here, like mine i run my window cmd
    CommandLine cmdLine = CommandLine.parse(line);
    DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor(); 
    int exitValue = executor.execute(cmdLine);

    }
    catch (Exception exc){     
       System.out.println("error" + exc);/*handle exception*/} 
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jason now  i can execute my .exe application

My code now is

```
package apacherunsshkeygen;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.exec.CommandLine;
import org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor;
import org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteWatchdog;


public class ApacheRunSSHKEygen {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    try {

//        String line = "AcroRd32.exe /p /h " + file.getAbsolutePath();
    String line = "C:\\ExecuteSSH\\ssh-keygen.exe";
    CommandLine cmdLine = CommandLine.parse(line);
    DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();

    //watchdog
    executor.setExitValue(1);
    ExecuteWatchdog watchdog = new ExecuteWatchdog(60000);
    executor.setWatchdog(watchdog);

    int exitValue = executor.execute(cmdLine);
    }

    catch (Exception exc){

       System.out.println("error" + exc);/*handle exception*/} 
    }


   }
```